# NullPointerException [no message] -- how can I find its source?

Tags: clojure, luminus

I have `NullPointerException [no message]` in my luminus application. The code is quite long to post it here and I can't find the source of the error. Neither there's any mention of "NullPointerException [no message]" in the logs, and in the browser the error just doesn't make sense and  the exact place and variables where the error is caused aren't shown precisely.

How can I trace what causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

the approach that i take for such errors is

- if it is a new error (started happening recently), then most probably it is being caused by the code that was added recently. so use that code as the starting point
- see if there are any API calls which might be returning a `nil` value. try to replace every API w/ a real hardcoded value, one-by-one, and see if you're still seeing the error
- once you figure out which API call is returning `nil`, then dig deeper to see if you're passing any wrong arguments to the API, or causing some case due to which it is returning the `nil`

HTH :)

Comment: `then dig deeper to see if you're passing any wrong arguments to the API,` -- bingo. so how?

Comment: you need to check the signature (source code and/or documentation) of the API. ps: by API i really meant any internal/external function

Answer (score 0):

Clojure's error messages can be hell but they aren't useless. Take a look at this link:

https://8thlight.com/blog/connor-mendenhall/2014/09/12/clojure-stacktraces.html

It helped me out and hope it can do the same for you

Answer (score -1):

Null pointer exception is caused because of accessing / using a variable which holds the value. As a programmer we have to do null chuck to the variable which are returning a value from other functions.

If you want to trace it just keep debug point from which action you are getting this error n chuck which variable your accessing as null value.

Comment: "If you want to trace it just keep debug point from which actio" -- how?

Comment: action ( in struts) / controller which cause you to throw exception.

Comment: or if you know which class / method is throwing exception then keep break point before entering or beginning of  class / method

Comment: "If you want to trace it just keep debug point from which action" -- how exactly to put a break point?